# React - Running side effects inside pure functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-hooks

## Introduction

My current use case requires to store the most fresh state updates in a cache. As state updates are async, and there can be a lot of components updating the same one in parallel, it might be a good option to store them inside the body of the useState or useReducer pure functions.

But... side effects come, and the frustration start. I have tried to await dispatches, creating custom hooks "useReducerWithCallback", and other stuff, but I don't see the correct solution to my problem.

## Problem

I have a module usersCache.js which provides me with the necessary methods to make modifications to my cache:

```
const cache = {};

export const insert = (id, data) => ...

export const get = (id) => ...

// and more stuff
```

I am trying to update this cache when I make state updates. For example:

```
 const currentUser = useContext(CurrentUserContext);
 
 ...

 // Note: setData is just the state setter useState hook
 currentUser.setData((prevData) => {
     const newTotalFollowing = prevData.totalFollowing + 1;

     usersCache.update(currentUser.data.id, { newTotalFollowing }); <---- SIDE EFFECT
     
     return { ...prevData, totalFollowing: newTotalFollowing };
 });
```

And same stuff in my otherUsers **reducer**

```
import { usersCache } from "../../services/firebase/api/users"

export default (otherUsers, action) => {   
    switch (action.type) {
       case "follow-user": {
          const { userId, isFollowing } = action;

          const prevUserData = otherUsers.get(userId);

          const newTotalFollowers = prevUserData.totalFollowers + (isFollowing ? 1 : -1);

          usersCache.update(userId, { totalFollowers: newTotalFollowers }); // merge update

          return new Map([
             ...otherUsers,
            [
                userId,
                {
                   ...prevUserData,
                   totalFollowers: newTotalFollowers
                 ]
            ]
         );
       }

       ...
    }
}
```

As in pure functions we shouldn't perform side effects... Is there any other approach to handle this?

Note: I am not using Redux

Comment: The solution [`useEffect()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

Comment: @RandyCasburn but as the state updates are async... if, for example, there are multiple components trying to update the same state in parallel, wouldn't the useEffect callbacks be executed in a messy way?

Comment: You are not even using the usersCache in the examples you've given. Since that user state is already in that React context, what exactly would be problem be if you just removed the usersCache module?

Comment: If you remember your ACID theory, data consistency is a tradeoff of event-sourced systems. It's possible that one component could emit a delete on some context state, then another component could emit an update using out-of-date state as a reference. This is a common problem for offline capable systems, but is it actually an issue in your application?

Comment: Write a FIFO queue that queues up the state changes.

Comment: @windowsill I have also thought to use the Context state as a cache, but there are two problems with that: 1. The Context Provider is only wrapping my protected routes (react navigation’s protected routes pattern for managing authentication flow).   

 2. In every user object that is stored in my otherUsers context, there is a field “isFollowed” which is relative to the current user. So, when the user logs out and re login with other user credentials, and if the context wasn’t un mounted, the data would be inconsistent between cache and database.

Comment: @windowsill BTW, I know that duplicating data will have side effects (increasing memory, for example). That’s why in my real scenario, every object which is stored in cache has a timeout (some cache’s algorithm to avoid consuming lot of memory). Also, I will play with JSON.stringify()  and JSON.parse() to perform some minimal optimizations on it. But the main idea is to check the cache, before every DB request, in my api modules, to return possible cached data. And, as we can only consume contexts inside hooks or React Components, having this extra cache simplify my life.

Comment: Thanks for the extra info, it would have been very helpful to include in your question! You're on the right track, it's never going to be pretty (or pure). If you want to avoid denormalizing your state into a cache then you can make a hook like useFetchIfNeeded that accepts an api function and a key to look for state in the Context. Or keep doing what you're doing, but make a hook like useStateWithAPICache that also takes a key that you add to your cache object.

Answer (score 1):

You can check this [full working example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fmyajJetOyg&t=4s) using the repository pattern and react hooks to simplify async actions with state dispatches. I know you are not using redux but you can adapt this example using the useReducer hook to connect it to your React Context store.

Comment: It looks like this video is no longer available.